# Favicon doesn't change

Tags: html, favicon

I am creating my first website and initially I added a favicon called "preview.ico" (saved in a local file) to be the icon of my page tab, and now I want to change it but if I try to change it for another image from the same folder or completely delete the icon line from the code, the old icon is still showing somehow, even if it doesn't show in the code and it is saved. What have I done wrong?

The following code is the original one for the header:

```
<head>
<div id="header">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Quicksand:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Caveat:wght@700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/style.css"
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="discription" content="Travel">
    <meta name="keywords" content="travel, blog, exchange program, experience, tips">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>FlaViagens
    </title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="images/ico" href="images/preview.ico">
</div>
```

And I want to change it to another image, specifically for a png image instead of .ico. However, even if i **completely** delete `<link rel="shortcut icon" type="images/ico" href="images/preview.ico">` line, it still shows in the tab (?)

[Check how the tab shows atm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vwzb7.png)

I am still learning HTML and CSS so if anyone find any other mistakes in this small part of my code it would be great to have a feedback. Also not sure if it's worth to mention but I am using Visual Studio Code.

Cheers!

Comment: Maybe just be cached.

Comment: clear the cache and reload the page

Comment: As @EpicChen mentioned, clear the cache, and then do a hard reload using `ctrl+shift+r`. Also, note that png favicons need to have a certain size &  cannot be used in the browser tab as a favicon. You need to convert 'em to a `.ico` format first.

Comment: Why do you have a `div` in your `head` element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<header></header>` and `<head></head>`  are two seperate things.

`header` or a `div` with the `id='header'` or a `class='header'`  is used to group HTML elements that are used to display, you guessed it, a header.

`head` on the other hand has no visual apperance (aside from the title and the favicon), and defines info about the page, including meta info, title, references to external file such as stylesheets, scripts, etc.

Maybe, try to remove the `div` inside the `head` tag? like so:

```
<head>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Quicksand:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Caveat:wght@700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/style.css"
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="discription" content="Travel">
    <meta name="keywords" content="travel, blog, exchange program, experience, tips">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>FlaViagens</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="images/ico" href="images/preview.ico">
</head>
```

Comment: Thank you, that explains a lot! :D 
My issue was with cache + using <div> in a wrong place, like you explained. Cheers!